# Android: How to get the native Email clients package name

Tags: android, email

In Samsung devices  **com.sec.android.email**  is the default In-Built Mail client, but in HTC it is **com.htc.android.mail**.. My question is is there any way to get the default mail client package name in android device irrespective of the different company builds..

Comment: You want the person default e-mail package app?

Comment: Not the default.Since we can make a thrid party Email-client as our device default Email client.. I need the in built mail client for each device

Comment: I think the best you can do is get a list of Activities that can send a `message/rfc822` and iterate over them to inspect their package names, but that won't tell you whether they are the default. Why do you need this, if I may ask?

Comment: @Karakuri How to find a app can send message/rfc822, i couldnt get a way to do that.. Just to monitor the application in android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but here is how to get a list of Activities that can send `message/rfc822`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
PackageManager pkgManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

You can iterate over the list. See [`ResolveInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) documentation for fields of interest.

Comment: but this prints Gmail instead of Email in Samsung Device :( . I am nt getting all the email packages

Comment: Yes this not a full answer. The answer is we cant get like that