# Intent.ACTION_SENDTO show two options , I want to show only one

Tags: android, android-intent

Intent.ACTION_SENDTO in shows two options but my clent is asking to remove the gmail option and i don't see a way out please help me

```
  Intent emailIntent =
 new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
 Uri.fromParts( "mailto",userInput.getText().toString(), null));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Press Release");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please view this press release");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail using..."));
```

[image]

Comment: It will show all default possible action which are available in device. As the device will have Gmail app, this chooser will show Gmail, too.

Comment: did you mean you want to open Email Composer directly or only to remove Gmail.?

Comment: my need is to remove gmail from this intent as i understand , but tell if there is a way to directly go to email composer without showing both of these icons

Comment: Not sure. But you may try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12636922/1777090)

Comment: [Android - How to open the email client directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12275494/1160282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 
`emailIntent.setPackage(PackageName of Email app);` before calling startActivity.

---

*You need to set email client package name but, in Samsung devices `com.sec.android.email` is the default In-Built Mail client, but in HTC it is `com.htc.android.mail` and so on. So first you need to filter that application and then set to intent. I am adding the solution*

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto", userInput.getText().toString(), null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Press Release");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "Please view this press release");

// Identify the package name of email client and set to intent
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(".android.email")
                || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(".android.email")) {
            emailIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            // And now call
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail using..."));
        }
    }
}
```

---

You should read [Android: How to get the native Email clients package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353600/android-how-to-get-the-native-email-clients-package-name)

Comment: i think `com.google.android.gm` is a packagename of Gmail app while question is about **but my clent is asking to remove the gmail option**

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU WANT TO REMOVE GMAIL CLIENT FROM LIST   create a custom cooser

```
  List<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    Intent neededShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    neededShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    neededShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                    neededShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                    if (!StringUtils.equals(packageName, "com.google.android.gm")){
                        intents.add(neededShareIntent);
                    }

                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intents.remove(0), "Select app to share");

                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
```

Pls test this code and check

Comment: i think `com.google.android.gm` is a packagename of Gmail app while question is about **but my clent is asking to remove the gmail option**

Comment: buddy I copied your code but still showing me both icons

Comment: What about if he has three email clients on device??

Comment: for that he should set the default email client package name as you said. :)

Comment: @deniz buddy what is targetedShareIntent in your code and where to declare it

Comment: sorry for the typo.... change that to neededShareIntent and try. updated answer pls check